# useState and callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

In the class component, the `setState()` method can take a callback function, but in a functional component when I give a callback to costume setState this warning occurs:
Warning: State updates from the `useState()` and `useReducer()` Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with `useEffect()`.
I need my state set, and then the page will redirect. But I don't have any idea.

Comment: The warning you are getting there is trying to give you the idea actually. You can use `useEffect` for this.

Comment: Hi, if you would like a more explicit answer feel free to share any code that is troubling you and we will be able to help better

Comment: What if your functional component remain class component? is there any special concern for that?

Comment: @devserkan How can I useEffect for this situation?

Comment: @tareqaziz I have to use functional components.

Comment: @techguru I've already accepted it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of passing a `callback` function,  use `useEffect` hook, and do something like this to achieve the desired result.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state changed', your-state-variable)
    // write your callback function here
  }, [your-state-variable]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful! In a class component, you can call a callback function right after each `setState` that you want, but in the functional component, the `useEffect` hook run after any changing state that happens in the whole of your component.
To handle this challenge, you should be careful in choosing your state and how to set it.

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hamilton-d3u49?file=/src/App.js:0-2405) is a very simple example:

```
import { Grid, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [background, setBackground] = useState("white");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setBackground("white"), 100);
  }, [background]);

  const countIncreamentHandler = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
    setBackground("rgba(112, 181, 0, .2)");
  };
  const countDecreamentHandler = () => {
    setCount((count) => count - 1);
    setBackground("rgba(181, 9, 0, .2)");
  };

  return (
    <Grid container justify="space-around">
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={countIncreamentHandler}
      >
        +
      </Button>
      <Typography style={{ padding: 5, background }} variant="h5">
        {count}
      </Typography>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        onClick={countDecreamentHandler}
      >
        -
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

In class component:

```
export class ClassCompontet extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      background: "white"
    };
  }

  countIncreamentHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        count: prevState.count + 1,
        background: "rgba(112, 181, 0, .2)"
      }),
      () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ background: "white" });
        }, 100);
      }
    );
  };
  countDecreamentHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        count: prevState.count - 1,
        background: "rgba(181, 9, 0, .2)"
      }),
      () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ background: "white" });
        }, 100);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={this.countIncreamentHandler}
        >
          +
        </Button>
        <Typography
          style={{ padding: 5, background: this?.state?.background }}
          variant="h5"
        >
          {this?.state?.count}
        </Typography>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          onClick={this.countDecreamentHandler}
        >
          -
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```